# $\mathrm{Hom}(\lim_IA_i,B)=\mathrm{colim}_I(\mathrm{Hom}(A_i,B))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $I$ be a cofiltered index category, $A_i$ be a directed system of $R$-modules. Is the following true?

$$\mathrm{Hom}(\lim_IA_i,B)=\mathrm{colim}_I(\mathrm{Hom}(A_i,B))$$

(Note this is not true for arbitrary limits, for example if $I$ is the discrete category.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Q}$, $I=\mathbb{N}$, and $A_n=\mathbb{Q}^n$ connected by the obvious projection maps.  The inverse limit $\lim A_n$ is then $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$, which has uncountable dimension.  In particular, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Q})$ is uncountable.  But $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}^n,\mathbb{Q})$ is countable for each $n$, and so it follows that the direct limit is also countable.

In fact, you can find a counterexample for any nonzero module $B$ at all: see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1981030/86856).

Comment: Ok. I think it a bit strange. There're natural isomorphisms $\mathrm{Hom}(P,\lim Q)\cong ...$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{colim}P,Q)\cong...$) by universal properties. Moreover, for directed index, we have $\mathrm{Hom}(M,\mathrm{colim}_IM_i)=\mathrm{colim}_I(\mathrm{Hom}(M,N_i))$, is there a "lim" counterpart for this?

Comment: Probably the right dual isomorphisms are $\operatorname{Hom} (X, \operatorname{lim} Y_i) \cong \operatorname{lim} \operatorname{Hom} (X, Y_i)$ and $\operatorname{Hom} (\operatorname{colim} X_i, Y) \cong \operatorname{lim} \operatorname{Hom} (X_i, Y)$?

Comment: @Qixiao: That last statement you wrote is only true if $M$ is finitely presented, so you would expect a dual statement to hold only if $M$ is "co-finitely presented".  However, I think that the only "co-finitely presented" modules are $0$, though I haven't checked carefully.  In any case, it shouldn't be too surprising that some statements like this can't be dualized: all that's going on is that $R\text{-Mod}^{op}$ is not a category of modules over some ring.

Comment: The dual notion to being finitely generated is: $M$ is finitely cogenerated if and only if for every injective map $ M \to \prod_{i\in I} M_i$ there exists $J$ a finite subset of $I$ such that $M\to \prod_{j\in J} M_i$ is still injective. Can this iterate to finitely copresentedness?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I had thought the last isomorphism is always true.. is there a counter example for $I$ directed index category and $M$ not finitely generated?Thank you!

Comment: @Qixiao: Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as the filtered colimit of its cyclic subgroups and $M=\mathbb{Q}$.  There is no nonzero map $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ so the right hand side of your equation is $0$, but the left hand side is nonzero since there are nonzero maps $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I have posted a question about whether there can be any nontrivial "co-finitely presented" modules at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980817/can-a-nonzero-module-be-cocompact.